# react-router-dom: how to create route with regex capture groups in url and get them in the component

Tags: react-router-dom

I want to create a page in reactjs for the following regex url

```
^rest-auth/password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$
```

And i want to capture `uidb64` and `token` in my component

Can any one guide how to write route with regex

I am using the

```
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react": "16.13.1",
```

currently i have

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "./views/User/Login";
import Signup from "./views/User/SignUp";
import ForgotPasswordSendEmail from "./views/User/ForgotPasswordSendEmail";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  
    <Router history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/forgort-password-send-email" component={ForgotPasswordSendEmail} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/login" /> 
      </Switch>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Now i want to add a Component called `ResetPassword` something like below

```
import ResetPassword from "./views/User/ResetPassword";
<Route path="/rest-auth/password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$" component={ResetPassword} />
```

and my `ResetPassword` Component looks like

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function ResetPassword() {
    // Here how to capture the urls capture groups
    // and then store then as follows
    const uid = uid64;
    const token = token;
    return (
    <div>
    {uid} -- {token}
    </div>

}
```

HOw to do routing with regex capture groups and how to get them in  my component.

Answer (score 0):

To Capture regex groups we have to use `/name:regex` and use useParams hook

```
<Route path="/rest-auth/password-reset/confirm/uidb64:([0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/token:([0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$" component={ResetPassword} />
```

and inside ResetPassword

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function ResetPassword() {
    let params = userParams()
    const uid = params.uid64;
    const token = params.token;
    return (
    <div>
    {uid} -- {token}
    </div>

}
```